# Can't insert into database by using ExecuteNonQuery() and stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, executenonquery

Language: C#
Skill: Beginner
Tool: Visual Studio 2010

Hello StackOverflow,

I have made a stored procedure for inserting data into a table...

Stored proc works fine when I execute it in Server Explorer and it inserts into that table...

But when I call this stored proc from my code, I got output "1 row affected" but no data is inserted into the table ...!

I'm puzzled what is happening.

```
private void btn_AssignTeacher_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   bool result = false;

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sprocInsert");

   int teacherid = comboBox_teachername.SelectedIndex +1;
   int coursesinfoid = comboBox_coursename.SelectedIndex+1;
   int daysid = comboBox_day.SelectedIndex+1;
   int slotsid = comboBox_slot.SelectedIndex+1;

   cmd.Parameters.Add("@coursesinfoid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = coursesinfoid;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@daysid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = daysid;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@slotsid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = slotsid;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@teacherid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = teacherid;

   result = AssignCoursesMgr.Insert(cmd);

   if (result == true) 
      MessageBox.Show("teacher assign successfully");
}

class AssignCoursesManager
{
   DBLayer DBworks;

   public bool Insert(SqlCommand cmd)
   {
        DBworks = new DBLayer();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        return DBworks.InsertData(cmd);
    }
}

public bool InsertData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        int result = 0;
        SqlConnection conn = CreateConnection(ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        if (result > 0)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

And here is the "sprocInsert"

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sprocInsert
(
 @coursesinfoid int,
 @teacherid int,
 @daysid int,
 @slotsid int
)
AS
 INSERT INTO schedule (coursesinfoid,teacherid,daysid,slotsid)
 VALUES(@coursesinfoid,@teacherid,@daysid,@slotsid)
```

Comment: Are you commiting after you execute procedure? use `using(){}` to make sure your changes are commited

Comment: what do you mean by "commiting" ? I have used Try/Catch instead of "using(){}"

Comment: Looks like changes run through but they don't get commited.

Comment: Yes all code executes..i have checked thru debugger and results in "1 Row Affected"...But NO entry in DB ?

Comment: Just a note: I personally would define the type (text/stored proc) right where I create the `SqlCommand` - not two or three method calls later.....

Comment: No effect,I just tried your tip...

Comment: Marc_s tip wouldn't make a difference - just good practice. Are you sure your command string is correct and doesn't point to a test instance somewhere - either a test database or an entirely different server?

Comment: well i have just used one DB and one ConnectionString...

Comment: Same InsertData() is used in another event handler and it inserts in DB but not anywhere else...